# Assert self.caps, 'Driver capabilities must be defined'

Tags: python, android, selenium, automation, appium

When running the following code to automate opening chrome browser on my android device I see the following error

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import time

from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


DC_USER_NAME = 'admin'
DC_API_KEY = ''
DC_DEVICE_ID = 'd6b54c70-fc07-49a4-9737-11daee82f19c'
DC_HOST = 'localhost'


APP_PACKAGE = ''
APP_ACTIVITY = ''

AUTOMATION_NAME = 'UiAutomator2'
desired_caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

caps = {
    'gigafox:UserName'      : DC_USER_NAME,
    'gigafox:ApiKey'        : DC_API_KEY,
    'gigafox:Device'        : DC_DEVICE_ID,
    'gigafox:application'   : '',
    'newCommandTimeout'     : 1000,
    #'appPackage'            :APP_PACKAGE,
    #'appActivity'           :APP_ACTIVITY,
    'platformName'          : 'Android',
    'browserName'           : 'Chrome',
    'automationName'        : AUTOMATION_NAME
}


url = 'http://{0}/Appium'.format(DC_HOST)
print('loading driver')

driver = webdriver.Remote(url, caps)
print('connected.')

driver.Quit()
```

**Error return**

Automation Scripts % python3 connectAndroid.py
loading driver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kris/Desktop/Github/Automation Scripts/connectAndroid.py", line 51, in 
driver = webdriver.Remote(url, caps)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 244, in **init**
self._update_command_executor(keep_alive=keep_alive)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 285, in _update_command_executor
assert self.caps, 'Driver capabilities must be defined'
AssertionError: Driver capabilities must be defined

My device wakes up and connects but when the browser is opened I see an error on the screen and the above is output in terminal

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding the following caps:

```
{
  "appium:deviceName": "#find serial nr of phone from running adb devices on cmd",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\#full path of the apk you want to open",
  "appium:udid": "#repeat serial nr of phone"
}
```

Comment: I did attempt that but it said I did not have the capabilities needed to start the session and no session was started. I reverted t  his back to the default from before. The app is already installed on the phone and the software allows the server to install the app from the repo so as long as I have the name correct it will install it. the funny thing is this doesnt stop the app from showing up. The app gets opened it just abruptly stops.
The appium interacts with the server using the substitute name gigafox. I hope that may clear things up.